# Spark Wordcount error (The vocabulary size should be > 0) when creating a new spark context in spark-shell

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

When I start a spark-shell using localhost and run the folloiwng wordcount script, I got the correct output:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Word2Vec1 {
  def main() {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR)  
    Logger.getLogger("com").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      "Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "),
      "I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "),
      "Logistic regression models are neat".split(" ")
    ).map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("text")

    val word2Vec2 = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setVectorSize(3)
      .setMinCount(0)
    val model = word2Vec2.fit(documentDF)

    val result = model.transform(documentDF)
    result.collect().foreach { case Row(text: Seq[_], features: Vector) =>
      println(s"Text: [${text.mkString(", ")}] => \nVector: $features\n")
    }
  }
}

Word2Vec1.main
```

The output is

```
Text: [Hi, I, heard, about, Spark] =>
Vector: [-0.028139343485236168,0.04554025698453188,-0.013317196490243079]

Text: [I, wish, Java, could, use, case, classes] =>
Vector: [0.06872416580361979,-0.02604914902310286,0.02165239889706884]

Text: [Logistic, regression, models, are, neat] =>
Vector: [0.023467857390642166,0.027799883112311366,0.0331136979162693]
```

However, if I tried to start a new sparkContext inside the spark-shell, I got the error

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkConf, SparkContext}
import org.apache.log4j.{Level, Logger}
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec
import org.apache.spark.ml.linalg.Vector
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Word2Vec1 {
  def main() {
    Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR) 
    Logger.getLogger("com").setLevel(Level.ERROR)

    val conf = new SparkConf()
      .setMaster("local")  
      .setAppName("Word2Vec1")
      .set("spark.driver.allowMultipleContexts", "true")
      .set("spark.cores.max", "4")
      .set("spark.executor.memory", "2g")
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val spark = SparkSession
      .builder
      .appName("Word2Vec1")
      .getOrCreate()

    val documentDF = spark.createDataFrame(Seq(
      "Hi I heard about Spark".split(" "),
      "I wish Java could use case classes".split(" "),
      "Logistic regression models are neat".split(" ")
    ).map(Tuple1.apply)).toDF("text")

    val word2Vec2 = new Word2Vec()
      .setInputCol("text")
      .setOutputCol("result")
      .setVectorSize(3)
      .setMinCount(0)
    val model = word2Vec2.fit(documentDF)

    val result = model.transform(documentDF)
    result.collect().foreach { case Row(text: Seq[_], features: Vector) =>
      println(s"Text: [${text.mkString(", ")}] => \nVector: $features\n")
    }
    sc.stop
  }
}
Word2Vec1.main
```

The error is

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The vocabulary size should be > 0. You may need to check the setting of minCount, which could be large enough to remove all your words in sentences.
  at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:281)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.learnVocab(Word2Vec.scala:200)
  at org.apache.spark.mllib.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:311)
  at org.apache.spark.ml.feature.Word2Vec.fit(Word2Vec.scala:186)
  at Word2Vec1$.main(<pastie>:66)
  ... 50 elided
```

This is the minimal reproducible example I can come up with but don't know what to do next.

My spark version: 2.4.4
Using Scala version 2.12.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_232)

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks but I have already set the MinCount to be zero for both cases.

Comment: Another idea is to NOT `.setLevel(Level.ERROR)` for everything, and see if you can spot any issues in the output.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @mazaneicha! I figured out where the issue might be. The sparkSession created in the second example is actually using the original sparkContext. Then it seems that two contexts are affecting each other and that blocks the Word2Vec's access to the created dataframe. So it deems the dataframe as empty and pops the error.